# Can't get it to iterate through a range Apps Script Not working In Loop Only on One Value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm confused as to why my function is returning blank when trying to loop through multiple when the same doesn't when doing one. This my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4hhDaQnH--_ZqaGXp7h6HnhTTFYzbM0MeuHsT-ak1w/edit#gid=0
This is my code:

```
//arrays input
function testCustom(term, startDate,amount, name, soldBy) 
{

  var results = new Array(term.length);


  //loop through every term number in array 
  for(var f = 0; f < term.length; f++)
  {

    //loop through term count
    for(var i = 0; i < term[f]; i++)
    {
      //arrray to store all terms
      var termTempArray = new Array(term[f]);

      //add increment to date
      var newDate = new Date();
      newDate = startDate;
      var thirdDate = new Date();
      thirdDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth()+i);

      //create a new array full of payment date info 
      var payDate = new Array(4);
      payDate[0] = name;
      payDate[1] = thirdDate;
      payDate[2] = amount;
      payDate[3] = soldBy;

      termTempArray[i] = payDate;
      results[f] = termTempArray;
    }


  }

  return results;


}
```

This code works where as the above returns blank

```
 //arrays input
function frack(term, startDate,amount, name, soldBy) 
{
  var results = new Array(term);
  //loop through every term number in array 
  //for(var f = 0; f < term.length; f++)
  //{
    //loop through term count
    for(var i = 0; i < term; i++)
    {
      //add increment to date
      var newDate = new Date();
      newDate = startDate;
      var thirdDate = new Date();
      thirdDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth()+i);

      //create a new array full of payment date info 
      var payDate = new Array(3);
      payDate[0] = name;
      payDate[1] = thirdDate;
      payDate[2] = amount;
      payDate[3] = soldBy;

      //add array to results
      results[i] = payDate;
    }
  //}

  return results;


}
```

Instead of having to manually use the second bit of code for every row of data I want to have something that iterates through the range of values and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm new to javascript and google apps script, but not to programming at large.

Comment: Your sheets is currently inaccessible, can you share the sample data to the public? If you could include the parameter values and the expected output, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle 2D arrays correctly. It is perhaps easier to get all data as one array, and call the function like this:

`=RepeatByNumberOfTerms(A2:E)`

...where each row in `A2:E` contains one record, such as:

| Terms | Date | Amount | Name | Sold by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 5/12/2022 | 100 | Jill Smith | Dweezil |
| 2 | 5/12/2021 | 20 | Jane Jones | Moon Unit |

You can then use [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), like this:

```
/**
* Repeats name, amount and soldBy, incrementing date by one month each time.
*
* @param {A2:E} data A range where each row contains term, startDate, amount, name, soldBy.
* @customfunction
*/
function RepeatByNumberOfTerms(data) {
  'use strict';
  if (!Array.isArray(data) || data[0].length !== 5) {
    throw new Error('Expected a range with at least one row of five columns.');
  }
  const result = [];
  data.forEach(row => {
    const [terms, startDate, amount, name, soldBy] = row;
    if (!Number(terms)) {
      return;
    }
    if (!startDate.getMonth) {
      throw new Error(`Expected a date, but '${startDate}' is a ${typeof startDate}.`);
    }
    const startMonth = startDate.getMonth();
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(1000, terms); i++) {
      const date = new Date(startDate);
      date.setMonth(startMonth + i);
      result.push([name, date, amount, soldBy]);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

This gets the following results:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jill Smith | 5/12/2022 | 100 | Dweezil |
| Jill Smith | 6/12/2022 | 100 | Dweezil |
| Jill Smith | 7/12/2022 | 100 | Dweezil |
| Jane Jones | 5/12/2021 | 20 | Moon Unit |
| Jane Jones | 6/12/2021 | 20 | Moon Unit |